# MBP 2010 no longer shows native resolution with LG Ultrawide (2560x1080) over miniDP

Tags: display, resolution, displayport, driver

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) and an LG 25UM64-S Ultrawide monitor. For 2+ years I had the Ultrawide connected by mini-displayport and got the full/native resolution of 2560x1080.

But just this morning, the max resolution dropped to 1080p according to the displays applet. The MBP said it had restarted overnight (some kind of update?) but otherwise nothing changed.

I just did another update and the MBP is now running OSX 10.10.5 but that didn't fix the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295), boot once without the external, then again with.

Comment: it 'almost' worked. It showed full res during boot, but then it switched back to 1080p. When I FIRST opened the Displays app, it showed 2560x1080 as an option, but when I tried to select, it spun the cursor, then all the resolution choices disappeared. still at 1080p